# Why is my map marker not rendering when generated via .map() in React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, react-native

Using React Native with `react-native-maps` on Android external device over Wifi.

I made a component called MapMarker which takes props `title` and `coordinates`. Inside my `<MapView></MapView>`, I can render it like so:

```
<MapMarker
  coordinates={{
      longitude: -4.516095,
      latitude: 55.679897
  }}
  title="James"
/>
```

But I want to render my markers dynamically, so I have a state set up like:

```
    mapMarkers: [
        {
            latLng: {
                latitude: 55.679897,
                longitude: -4.516095,
            },
            title: "James"
        }
    ]
```

And when I try to map this state using `.map()`, it doesn't seem to hit the component. I know this because I have a `console.warn()` inside my `<Marker>` component. This is how I am using the `.map()` function:

```
 {this.state.mapMarkers.map((marker) => {
    <MapMarker
       coordinates={{
           longitude: marker.latLng.longitude,
           latitude: marker.latLng.latitude
       }}
       title={marker.title}
   />
 })}
```

Using the second method, the `console.warn()` (which is placed in `componentDidMount()`) is not triggered. I have dumped out `this.state.mapMarkers[0].longitude` and latitude onto the main screen and they're both correct/visible.

From a Vue background so not 100% on what I need to do differently with `.map()` for rendering components.

Comment: You need a `return` in your `map` call, or replace the function braces (`{}`) with parentheses

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you return the React component you are creating. The easiest way to do this is to take advantage of your arrow function and use parens instead of function brackets.

```
 {this.state.mapMarkers.map((marker) => (
    <MapMarker
       coordinates={{
           longitude: marker.latLng.longitude,
           latitude: marker.latLng.latitude
       }}
       title={marker.title}
   />
 ))}
```